# Unable to login with provided credentials

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, graphene-django

I am trying to automatically login the user when user signs up instead of redirecting to login page and then only login. However, I get an error

```
"errors": [
   "email",
   "Unable to login with provided credentials."
],
```

Here is what I have done:

```
def get_token(**user):
    data = {}
    if user.get('email') and user.get('password'):
        serializer = JSONWebTokenSerializer(data=user)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            token = serializer.object['token']
            user = serializer.object['user']
            data = {
                'user': user,
                'token': token
            }
            return data
        else:
            data = {
                'errors': serializer.errors
            }
            return data
    data = {
        'errors': 'Email or Password not provided'
    }
    return data

# creates the user but could not login
class Register(graphene.Mutation):
    '''
        Mutation to register a user
    '''
    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)
        password_repeat = graphene.String(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()
    token = graphene.String()
    user = graphene.Field(UserQuery)
    errors = graphene.List(graphene.String)

    def mutate(self, info, email, password, password_repeat):
        if password == password_repeat:
            try:
                serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data={
                    'email': email,
                    'password': password,
                    'is_active': False
                })
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    user = serializer.save()
                    user_identity = get_token(email=user.email, password=user.password)
                    if not user_identity.get('errors'):
                        return Register(success=True, user=user_identity.get('user'), token=user_identity.get('token'))
                    else:
                        return Register(success=False, token=None, errors=['email', 'Unable to login with provided credentials.'])
            except Exception as e:
                errors = [e]
                return Register(success=False, errors=errors)
            errors = ["password", "Passwords don't match."]
            return Register(success=False, errors=errors)


# this works
class Login(graphene.Mutation):
    """
    Mutation to login a user
    """
    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()
    errors = graphene.List(graphene.String)
    token = graphene.String()
    user = graphene.Field(UserQuery)

    def mutate(self, info, email, password):
        user_identity = get_token(email=email, password=password)
        if not user_identity.get('errors'):
            return Login(success=True, user=user_identity.get('user'), token=user_identity.get('token'))
        else:
            return Login(success=False, token=None, errors=['email', 'Unable to login with provided credentials.'])
```

If I directly login then it works but if I want to login when registering the user then it does not work so I am not able to pass the token when registering the user.

How can I automatically log in user when registering so I can pass the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that you are mutating your newly created user object as `NOT ACTIVE`.

Here in your code, you can see you are defining the newly created user as inactive

```
serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data={
    'email': email,
    'password': password,
    'is_active': False
})
```

`is_active: False` means the username and password might be valid but your account is disabled that is why you could not login during signup.

Also if can see the source code of `JSONWebTokenSerializer` which you are relying on, in the validate function it's checking if user is inactive then throw an error

## this is from [JSONWebTokenSerializer](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/serializers.py#L22) source code

```
def validate(self, attrs):
        credentials = {
            self.username_field: attrs.get(self.username_field),
            'password': attrs.get('password')
        }

        if all(credentials.values()):
            user = authenticate(**credentials)

            if user:
                if not user.is_active:
                    msg = _('User account is disabled.')
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

                payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)

                return {
                    'token': jwt_encode_handler(payload),
                    'user': user
                }
            else:
                msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "{username_field}" and "password".')
            msg = msg.format(username_field=self.username_field)
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
```

so, one solution that i can see is turn the `is_active` flag as true or remove `is_active: False` and it will work.